# How to keep session data after closing browser with CI3?

Tags: codeigniter, session-cookies

I want users to keep login even after their browser closed and restarted. I had been setting FALSE on sess_expire_on_close in config file when I was using CI2. But CodeIgniter3.0 doesn't have sess_expire_on_close. Could anyone tell me how to keep session data with CodeIgniter3.0, please? Or do I have to use cookie, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `sess_expiration` to, for example  7200 (2 hours) , The number of seconds you would like the session to last. If you would like a non-expiring session (until browser is closed) set the value to zero: 0

source :

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Thank you, Baci. Yeah, as mentioned there, it's "until browser closed." So it means that once you close the browser, the session data will be deleted. I'd like to keep users login until users click "logout" by themselves.

Comment: then just increase the time to  1 year , and then even if they close the browser the session won't be destroyed. when they say until browser is closed, that is if you set sess_expiration to zero, but you don't set it to zero the session will keep going on until the specified time

Comment: It seems like the best way. I'll do that way. Thank you, again :)